# php get dates for all sundays in a month

Tags: php

I want to be able to come up with a php function that takes in the parameters
year, month and the day and returns the dates for the given day in an array.

for eg. lets say the function looks like this:

```
function get_dates($month, $year, $day)
{
    ....
}
```

if I call the function as below:

```
get_dates(12, 2011, 'Sun');
```

I should get an array containing the values:

```
2011-12-04
2011-12-11
2011-12-18
2011-12-25
```

What would the function code look like?

Comment: SO is here for help with a problem - We're not going to write the function for you.

Comment: I found the closest answer to my question at the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293174/grab-all-wednesdays-in-a-given-month-in-php

Thank you

Comment: @nickb, but the OP didn't ask to write function for him. You could even answer that the code would contain some curly braces and dollar signs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sample

```
function getSundays($y,$m){ 
    $date = "$y-$m-01";
    $first_day = date('N',strtotime($date));
    $first_day = 7 - $first_day + 1;
    $last_day =  date('t',strtotime($date));
    $days = array();
    for($i=$first_day; $i<=$last_day; $i=$i+7 ){
        $days[] = $i;
    }
    return  $days;
}

$days = getSundays(2016,04);
print_r($days);
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you may want to find out the weekday of the 1st of month, that would help you to get the first sunday (or whatever day you're looking for), then you go in 7 days increments till the month is over.

Comment: I was able to find a resolution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$year="2023";
$month="05";
$start_date = $year."-".$month."-01";
$last_day =  date('Y-m-t',strtotime($start_date));
$total_week_days=array();
for ($i = 0; $i < ((strtotime($last_day) - strtotime($start_date)) / 86400); $i++)
{
if(date('l',strtotime($start_date) + ($i * 86400)) == "Sunday")
{
$total_week_days[]=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date) + ($i * 86400));
}    
}
print_r($total_week_days);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is variation of function above. Here you can choose which dates of days in month will be display. For example you want to display all Tuesdays in January 2019.

```
/*
 * @desc Funtion return array of dates. Array contains dates for custom
 *       days in week.
 * @input integer $year
 * @input integer $month - Month order number (1-12)
 * @input integer $dayOrderNumber - Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2 and Sunday is 7.
 * @return array $customDaysDates - Array of custom day's dates.
 */
function getCustomDaysDatesInMonth($year,$month,$dayOrderNumber){ 

    $date = "$year-$month-01";

    $firstDayInMonth = (integer) date('N',strtotime($date));
    $theFirstCustomDay = ( 7 - $firstDayInMonth + $dayOrderNumber)%7 + 1;
    $lastDayInMonth =  (integer) date('t',strtotime($date));

    $customDaysDates = [];

    for($i=$theFirstCustomDay; $i<=$lastDayInMonth; $i=$i+7 ){
        $customDaysDates[] = $i;
    }

    return  $customDaysDates;
}

$days = getCustomDaysDatesInMonth(2019,1, 2);
print_r($days);
```

The output should be:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 [2] => 15 [3] => 22 [4] => 29 )
```

This mean that 1st, 8th, 15th, 22th and 29th January in 2019 are Tuesdays.