# Need help with calendar algorithm

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to create a gag calendar app and need some help getting the algorithm correct to create a calendar like this:

```
Sunday
Jan Feb .. Dec
  2   6      4
  9  13     11
 16  20     18
 23  27     25
 30

Monday
Jan Feb .. Dec
  3   7      5
 10  14     12
 17  21     19
 24  28     26
 31
```

And so on...
I have the code from 
http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/display-a-month-as-a-calendar

But can't get the algorithm to do it like above.

Comment: what does your algorithm do at the moment? In what way is it not working.  We can't help if you don't give us some clues.

Comment: Have a look at this to see how to get the first weekday of a month, then for each new row just add 7 days to the previous row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924246/get-the-first-or-last-friday-in-a-month/924276#924276

Comment: @Sam Holder, the code just prints a standard calendar of months. What I'm looking for is different as you can see.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, not quite as simple as that.

Comment: @MB34, why not? First row, display the first Sunday in Jan, first Sunday in Feb, etc. Second row show the second Sunday in Jan, second Sunday in Feb, etc. The method I linked will get the first, second, etc. specific day of any given month.

Comment: @MB34 that's too complicated?  not sure how we can help if a fairly straightforward answer is too complicated.

Comment: Another option is to build a set of nested objects, we used ArrayLists. It's a little grungy but the basic structure is ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> and represents a nested structure of month<day of week<calendar day for day of week>>; i.e. January<Monday<1,7,14,21,28>, Tuesday<2,8,15,22,29>... Populate the required timespan up front and then display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model the desired output as a three-dimensional array

```
private static final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
private static final int WEEKS_IN_MONTH = 5;
private static final int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;
Integer dayNumber[DAYS_IN_WEEK][WEEKS_IN_MONTH][MONTHS_IN_YEAR];
```

Allocate it and fill it using standard Calendar methods that give you the indices, then iterate over it in row-major order to produce the output.