# PHP find first Thursday in a month

Tags: php, date, strtotime, unix-timestamp

I'm working on a time management program and was wondering how I would find the first Thursday in a certain month. Does PHP have any functions to aid with this? strtotime doesn't want to format some strings properly.

If i use `strtotime("first thursday december 2011")` it returns `1323302400` which is actually the second thursday (8th december).

If i use `strtotime("first thursday december 2011 - 1 week")` it returns `1322092800` which is 24th November.

Can someone lend a hand please!

Comment: This could possibly help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924246/get-the-first-or-last-friday-in-a-month

Comment: Note that many examples here will work, but they fundamentally missed your simple mistake which has a very simple solution.  See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8478145/538216

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read [PHP Bug #53539](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53539). The fix is to use `of`: `strtotime("first thursday of december 2011")`

Note that many DateTime bugs were fixed in PHP 5.3. If you are running < 5.3 you should really upgrade.

Comment: This is a great answer! It's a shame that strtotime is pure magic with almost no documentation.

Comment: @Josh I am starting to develop for the PHP Core.  I don't have any accepted patches *yet*, but whenever I find something like this I'm sure there is a bug report filed at http://bugs.php.net.  It just takes some careful searching :)

Comment: @Levi Thanks for the tip. If I come across an obscure bug like the above, I'll check out bugs.php.net before asking on SO.

Comment: Also I found out that `first thursday december 2011 + 1 second` also provides the correct answer.

Comment: This answer isn't working for me. `echo strtotime("first thursday of december 2011");` is returning nothing to the browser. I'm running PHP 5.2.15

Comment: @dotty If `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first thursday of december 2011'))` does not print the correct date, then you have definitely found a bug.  However, it is definitely a problem with the PHP version that has been corrected. Your specific case is fixed in PHP 5.3.  I know that there were a lot of datetime bugs prior to PHP 5.3

Comment: We must make clear that PHP 5.2 is end of live (EOL) and *was* back in Dec 2011. So please do not expect that bugs in PHP 5.2 are being fixed. Instead consider to upgrade to PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4.

Comment: @hakra I guess I didn't state that very well: PHP 5.2 has a lot of relative DateTime bugs which are fixed in PHP 5.3.  You SHOULD upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime('next thursday', strtotime('last day of november'));
```

or even cleaner:

```
strtotime('thursday', strtotime('1 december'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar function witten [here](http://filchiprogrammer.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/getting-the-first-monday-of-the-month/), for the first Monday of the month. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

strtotime('first friday', strtotime('2023-03-00'))

Answer (score -1):

```
 function firstThursdayOfMonth() {

    $today = getdate();
      $firstdayofmonth = date('Y-m') . '-01 00:00:01';


       if($today !=$firstdayofmonth) {
         echo $firstdayofmonth;
          }
         else if($firstdayofmonth != date('Y-m-d[3]'.'-01 00:00:01') ) {
       echo $today;
            }
        else {
       echo $today;
       }
         }
       echo firstThursdayOfMonth();
```

Comment: This isn't working at all. Your code will just return the 4th of the current month. Here's a call equivalent to yours: `date('d/04/Y')`

Comment: @EmilVikström did you actually try it to know that it's not working?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Here it is, hosted at my machine: http://lajm.eu/emil/dump/tmp_date.php

Comment: @EmilVikström updated the codes.i believe this should do the trick.