# PHP Find date based on weekday

Tags: php, html, echo

Is it possible to make a date based on the weekday in a given month and year.

Givens are Month and Year. For instance, let's assume we are in March 2013.

We need too know the third Tuesday. So our ending result would be March 19, 2013

Other examples
Weekdays Given in the March 2013:

First Friday  March 1, 2013

First Monday  March 4, 2013

Third Wednesday  March 20, 2013

Fifth Sunday  March 31, 2013

Fourth Saturday  March 23, 2013

Comment: I think, it's been pretty much answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924246/get-the-first-or-last-friday-in-a-month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class you can easily get the full date:

```
$dt = new DateTime('third tuesday march 2013');
echo $dt->format('l j. F Y');
// Tuesday 19. March 2013
```

There are quite a lot of [valid strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) that can be passed to the `DateTime` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

this accepts strings such as "first monday in march" "last wednesday in august" as date strings and gives you the unix timestamp for these particular dates