# check if current week contains the last friday of the month

Tags: php

I am trying creating a script that will change an image on a page if the last friday in the month is during the current week.

For example if I am on any of the day of week (Monday to Sunday) that contains the last friday of the month during the week I will get an output that differs from the rest of the month. However I asked another question based on this and I to something similar to this:

```
$last_friday = strtotime('last Friday of this month');

if (date("Y-m-d") == date("Y-m-d", $last_friday)) {

$output = "<img src='payday.jpg' />";

} else {

$output = "<img src='nomoneyyet.jpg' />;

}
```

But after testing this it doesn't work during the actual week. Is strtotime what I should be using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the First or Last Friday in a Month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924246/get-the-first-or-last-friday-in-a-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateTime class in PHP and the format output for comparison:

```
// Be sure to check your timezone `date_default_timezone_set`
$today       = new DateTime();
$last_friday = new DateTime('last Friday of this month');

// For testing
$friday_april = new DateTime('2014-4-25');

if ($today->format('Y-m-d') === $last_friday->format('Y-m-d')) {
  print 'Today is friday';
}

if ($friday_april->format('Y-m-d') === $last_friday->format('Y-m-d')) {
  print 'Yes, a test friday is also a friday';
}
```

Comment: This would only apply in April wouldn't it?

Comment: To check if it is correct :) You can create a DateTime from an arbitrary date (ex 'today' or '2014-8-12').

Comment: Sorry yeah that was me being stupid would it be correct using $today_date = new DateTime(); to replace $friday_april?

Comment: Yes, that works. I updated my answer to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime as

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('last friday of this month');

$current_date = new DateTime() ;

if($date == $current_date){
  $output = "<img src='payday.jpg' />";
}else{
  $output = "<img src='nomoneyyet.jpg' />";
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but I just tried this code using "third friday of this month" as a test and it didn't work

Comment: It is currently saturday here, so be sure to check your timezone settings!