# MySQL: need to calculate the last Friday of a month

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to solve a task: I have a table containing information about ships' battles. Battle is made of **name** and **date**. The problem is to get **the last friday of the month when the battle occurred**.

```
WITH num(n) AS(
SELECT 0 
UNION ALL
SELECT n+1 FROM num 
WHERE n < 31),
dat AS (
SELECT DATEADD(dd,  n,  CAST(battles.date AS DATE)) AS day, 
    dateadd(dd, 0, cast(battles.date as date)) as fight, 
    name FROM num,battles)
SELECT name, fight, max(day) FROM dat WHERE DATENAME(dw, day) = 'friday'
```

I thought there must be a **maximum of date** or something, but my code is wrong.

The result should look like this:

[image]

Please, help!!

P.S. DATE_FORMAT is not available

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the First or Last Friday in a Month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924246/get-the-first-or-last-friday-in-a-month)

Comment: @JohnP that post is regarding PHP code, this one is pure MySql. Although the PHP option may be the easiest for this task.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not strong in php, and in mysql also. And I can not use php

Comment: Are you sure this query is for **MySQL**, and not for SQL Server or some other RDBMS? (If this is MySQL, what version of MySQL supports common table expressions?)

Answer (score 0):

**Possible problem**: as spencer7593 noticed - and as I should have done and didn't - *your original query is not MySQL at all*. If you're porting a query that's OK. Otherwise this answer will not be helpful, as it makes use of MySQL functions.

The day you want is number 4 (0 being Sunday in MySQL).

So you want the last day of the month if the last day of the month is a 4; if the day of the month is a 5 you want a date which is 1 day earlier; if the day of the month is a 3 you want a date which is 1 day later, but that's impossible (the month ends), so you really need a date six days earlier.

This means that if the daynumber difference is negative, you want it modulo seven.

You can then build this expression (@DATE is your date; I use a fake date for testing)

```
SET @DATE='2015-02-18';
DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(@DATE), INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(@DATE))+7-4))%7 DAY);
```

It takes the last day of the month (`LASTDAY(@DATE)`), then it computes its weekday, getting a number from 0 to 6. Adds seven to ensure positivity after subtracting; then subtract the desired daynumber, in this case 4 for Friday.

The result, modulo seven, is the difference (always positive) from the last day's daynumber to the *wanted* daynumber. Since `DATE_SUB(date, 0)` returns the argument date, we needn't use `IF`.

```
SET @DATE='1962-10-20';
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(@DATE), INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(@DATE))+7-4))%7 DAY) AS friday;
+------------+
| friday     |
+------------+
| 1962-10-26 |
+------------+
```

Your query then would become something like:

```
SELECT `name`, `date`,
    DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(`date`),
       INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(`date`))+7-4))%7 DAY) AS friday
FROM battles;
```

Comment: @Len_D, your answer is the same as mine and you replied before me. Why did you delete your answer? As far as I can see it is correct.

Comment: @spencer7593, my own MySQL (5.6.17 on Linux x64) gives 4 for today. `weekday(now()), date_format(now(), '%W')` returns [ 4, 'Friday' ].

Comment: Which is not to say that I was right in writing *0 to 7* - it was actually 0 to **6**. I edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Iserni: My mistake, I was mistakenly thinking that `WEEKDAY` was a synonym for the MySQL `DAYOFWEEK` function. But it isn't. `WEEKDAY` returns 0 through 6, `DAYOFWEEK` (which is the function I use) returns 1 through 7.