# Get days between first day of a month and a specified week and week day

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I've the following problem: I'm try to calculate the days between the first day of the actuall month and a week and his week day. 
For example: actually it's february. I'll have the days between the first day of this month and the second wednesday. How I can do this as clean as possible?

Comment: Do you have any code to show of what isn't working for you?

Comment: My brain isn't working. I've no idea how I can practise this. Can someone give me a hint.

Comment: Read about CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear. This is half the way to the solution.

Comment: [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) could be interesting too.

Comment: Naive approach: start at `new DateTime(year, month, 1)`, see if `DayOfWeek` is what you want, if so increase found counter, add a day, repeat until found counter is what you want and return how many days you added.

Answer (score 1):

*Well*, you can get the first day of current month like;

```
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
```

And you can get second wednesday like;

```
DateTime secondWednesday = firstDay.AddDays(7);

while(secondWednesday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
{
   secondWednesday = secondWednesday.AddDays(1);
}
```

Since we try to get second wednesday, at worst case scenario, second wednesday will be number `8` of the current month. If the *1st* day is Wednesday, then second wednesday will be *8th* of the month. Other than that, day number will be bigger than `8`.

This is the most logical option that I can imagine at least..

I found great answer by [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924246/get-the-first-or-last-friday-in-a-month);

> The language-agnostic version:
>
> To get the first particular day of the month, start with the first day
>   of the month: yyyy-mm-01. Use whatever function is available to give a
>   number corresponding to the day of the week. Subtract that number from
>   the day you are looking for; for example, if the first day of the
>   month is Wednesday (2) and you're looking for Friday (4), subtract 2
>   from 4, leaving 2. If the answer is negative, add 7. Finally add that
>   to the first of the month; for my example, the first Friday would be
>   the 3rd.
>
> To get the last Friday of the month, find the first Friday of the next
>   month and subtract 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method that finds the first day of the month:

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime datetime)
{
    return datetime.AddDays(-(datetime.Day - 1));
}
```

Here's one that finds the next of any weekday:

```
public static DateTime Next(this DateTime datetime, DayOfWeek day)
{
    return datetime.AddDays(datetime.DayOfWeek < day ?
        day - datetime.DayOfWeek :
        7 + day - datetime.DayOfWeek);
}
```

Here's one that finds the first of any weekday in a month:

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime datetime, DayOfWeek day)
{
    DateTime first = datetime.FirstDayOfMonth();
    return first.DayOfWeek == day ? first : first.Next(day);
}
```

Now to find the second wednesday after the first day of the month:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime firstWednesday = now.FirstDayOfMonth(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
DateTime secondWednesday = firstWednesday.AddDays(7);

int difference = secondWednesday.Day - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without loops or conditionals:

```
DateTime NthWeekdayInCurrentMonth(int n, DayOfWeek day)
{
    var firstOfMonth = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(DateTime.Now.Day-1));
    var firstWeekDay = firstOfMonth.AddDays(day - firstOfMonth.DayOfWeek);
    var NthWeekDay = firstWeekDay.AddDays(7*(n-1));
}
```

You might want to add some bounds checking on `n` to make sure your result is always in the current month.

You can easily get the number of days between the resulting date and the first of the month as follow:

```
NthWeekdayInCurrentMonth(2, DayOfWeek.Wednesday).Day-1
```