# I Want To Get the First or Last Friday in a Month in Laravel using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm using laravel8. I want to get a date of `last Friday` and `first Friday` in a month. I'm using `Carbon`.

I tried the below code snippet, but it gave me the `carbon` instance along with the date of `previous Friday`

```
    $searchDay = 'Friday';
    $searchDate = new Carbon(); //or whatever Carbon instance you're using
    $last = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime("last $searchDay", $searchDate->timestamp));

    dd($last);
```

Today's date is `16-Sep-2022` and the Expected result should be `30-sep-2022` but that snippet gives me a result of `09-Sep-2022`***(the previous Friday date)***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That snippet works perfectly for me:

##### Solution 1:

```
    $month = (new Carbon())->monthName;       //September
    $year= (int)Carbon::now()->format('Y');   //2022  
    $last = Carbon::parse("Last friday of {$month} {$year}");
```

##### Solution 2:

```
 $last = Carbon::parse("Last friday of this month");
```

In this snippet, I fetch the `current month's` name and the current `year`. By putting those values in `Carbon:parse()` statement. I'm able to get every month's last Friday date using `Carbon`.

> If you want to get first `Friday` then you can replace `last` keyword with `first` in `Carbon::parse()` statement.

***For Second Solution Credit Goes to:*** [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822756/12719616)